# Javascript Function is not defined despite the fact that it is

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, undefined, frameset

I'm working on updating an old site designed for ie8 and uses framesets to manage the layout.

I'm adding a piece of code to one frame that will create a div on another frame and load content into it through AJAX.  The problem is, for whatever reason, it keeps saying my function is undefined when I call it through an onclick.  Weirdly enough, this only happens when it's loaded though AJAX, not when it's loaded as itsown page.

I've already checked the JS and there's no syntax errors anywhere on the page.

Here is the function I'm trying to run if anyone wants to see it:

```
function closePopup() {
    alert('');
}
```

I've removed all other javascript from the page and it still says it's undefined.

Edit: Here is the jQuery code to load the page:

```
var main = top.frames["Main"].document;
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var centeringDiv = $("<div />", main)
.css({
  "position": "absolute",
  "top": "25%",
  "text-align": "center",
  "width": "100%",
  "z-index": "100"
})
.appendTo(main.body);
var lookUpDiv = $("<span />", main)
.attr("id", "lookUpDiv")
.css({
  "background-color": "#ffffff",
  "padding": "10px",
  "text-align": "center"
})
.text("Loading: Please Wait.")
.load("associateLookup.asp")
.appendTo(centeringDiv);
```

Comment: How exactly are you loading it "through AJAX"?  When you drop page content by setting `.innerHTML`, `<script>` blocks are **not** evaluated.

Comment: I was using jquery .load() function with no selectors specified.

Comment: You should post that code, because that's where the problem lies.

Comment: OK good - the way you're loading the content *should* evaluate the script because jQuery explicitly does that for you. Are you sure that the content is actually loading? Do you see the "Loading: Please Wait" text?

Comment: Yes, I see the "Loading: Please Wait."  for about a minute and then all the HTML that should display comes up, I inspect the span and can see the script tag with my function in it.  If I click on a button that is supposed to fire the function, it gives and error, if I try to fire it from console, I still get the error, and if I hardcode and alert into the button, that works.

Comment: If you add a `console.log("Hello World");` line to the script block, do you see that it runs?  Your description of the problem makes it seem like the `<script>` isn't being run, but jQuery should be explicitly evaluating it. However it's a little picky - if the `<script>` tag is messed up (like, wrong "type" attribute) then it won't run. It's best to make inline scripts be wrapped with completely plain `<script>` tags - no "type" and no "language".

Comment: I removed the language attribute and added the console log.  "Hello World" did appear in the log, but the function is still not defined.

Comment: Well that's weird. The only thing I can imagine is that the code isn't running such that it's modifying the global context, but I don't understand how that's possible. As an experiment, you could try changing the function declaration to `window.closePopup = function() { alert(''); };` to explicitly create a global function. I am puzzled as to why that would be necessary however.

Comment: Well that's actually what I would have expected; like I said, it was an experiment. Is it possible that you've simply got a misspelling? Like, maybe the function name is not exactly the same between the function definition and the reference in the "onclick" value?

Comment: I copied and pasted the function name over to the onClick, still no luck.  I also pasted it into console and it didn't work.

Comment: Wait - I just realized that your code seems to be working between separate iframes. Each iframe is its own separate global context; code in one iframe can't directly reference code defined in another iframe without explicitly "finding" it (via `window.parent` or whatever). Could that be it?

Comment: Yes!  I changed my function declaration to `top.frames["Main"].closePopup = function() {` and it worked!  Thanks for the help.  
If you'd post that as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment above: when working with interconnected `<iframe>` content, it's important to remember that separate frames are treated as separate global contexts. Each has it's own `window`, in other words. It's possible to navigate references that link the frames, as the code in the OP is doing when it refers to `top.frames["Main"]`.  References in "onclick" etc. attributes also must take that into account; similarly, code that wants to add functions or global values to *other* frames must do so explicitly.